# Suitable engine for game with no movement

Tags: framework, game-development

I'm planning in creating some kind of iOS game. But the game will be just some kind of "get better over time without much gameplay". So there is not much movement. I'd like to animate some parts of my game however. For example if an achievement pops up.

I know there are many frameworks to work with like SpriteKit, Unity and so on. What would you recommend using?